# How do I apply different textures to multiple primitives? (Direct3D 9)

Tags: graphics, directx, direct3d

I am creating a game in which every primitive needs its own texture, but I can't seem to figure out how. I searched through Google but it only displays results about texture blending. Can you please tell me how to apply multiple textures on multiple non-indexed primitives? Or do they have to be indexed?

Comment: You can change textures by calling SetTexture before each of DrawPrimitives. What's the problem?

Comment: Thank you. I tried something similar before but I guess I just used it wrong. Please post this as answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Depending on the number of different textures you have this means you'll have a large number of draw calls. Usually you try to keep the number of draw calls as small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change textures by calling SetTexture before each of DrawPrimitives.

Answer (score 0):

I think using an [UV atlas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can solve your problem. An atlas is basically a large texture made up of smaller textures, like a photo collage. The UV coordinates of your vertices of course refer to the large texture, but if you know the position of your "small" textures, this is easy to calculate.
Of course you have to create that atlas texture first.

Comment: U and V values are floats and they aren't convenient enough for the precision i need.

Comment: This means you have so many textures, or your textures are so large that the precision of float does not allow addressing a particular pixel in an atlas texture?

Comment: Float is not good enough for addressing a particular pixel in an atlas texture. Maybe if it's a small atlas, but otherwise not. And yes, I'll need many textures.